# Last step in Apostol's Section 11.6 Lemma 2 (Dirichlet Series)

Tags: analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Apostol's IANT Section 11.6 on the half-plane of convergence presents and proves a Lemma 2.

**Question:** I can't understand the simplifications he does at the last step. The image below highlights the step.

**Notes:** My own attempts at explaining is to use

$$ \left|b^{\sigma_{0}-\sigma}-a^{\sigma_{0}-\sigma}\right|=\left|a^{\sigma_{0}-\sigma}-b^{\sigma_{0}-\sigma}\right|<a^{\sigma_{0}-\sigma}<2a^{\sigma_{0}-\sigma}$$

Is this correct?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known that $a<b$, so we have

$$
|b^{\sigma_0-\sigma}-a^{\sigma_0-\sigma}|=a^{\sigma_0-\sigma}-b^{\sigma_0-\sigma}
$$

Since it is also known that $b^{\sigma_0-\sigma}>0$, we obtain

$$
|b^{\sigma_0-\sigma}-a^{\sigma_0-\sigma}|<a^{\sigma_0-\sigma}
$$